# Specific categories products not loading in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, php-5.4, category-products

I am loading specific category products on a page, but it's not working properly, it's getting all the products that added.. not specificaly a category products..

Please help:

code i am using is :

```
$category2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(10);
    //$products->addCategoryFilter($category);
    $products2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
  $products2->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail', 'price')); //feel free to add any other attribues you need.
  Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products2);
  Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products2); 
  $products2->getSelect()->order('RAND()');
  $products2->getSelect()->limit(3);
```

Comment: why did you comment the addCategoryFilter method?

Comment: Because it was providing error at that place... so i commented that

Comment: It gives an error because you pass as a parameter `$category` but your var name above is `$category2`. Try it with `$category2` and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks buddy.. i now resolved it, i used this line inside the $products2 and its working properly.. it's not working alone..

Comment: Please write your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted. Let's keep this website clean.

Comment: I post an answer you can mark it as accepted... that code is working properly...

Comment: I cannot mark it as accepted. Only you can do that because you asked the question. There may be a time delay. SE may not allow you to accept the answer for the next 2 days. Just remember to come back and mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code is working properly:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(9);
    //$products->addCategoryFilter($category);
    //$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addCategoryFilter($category)->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail', 'price')); 

  //$products->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'thumbnail', 'price')); //feel free to add any other attribues you need.
  Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
  Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products); 
  $products->getSelect()->order('RAND()');
  $products->getSelect()->limit(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be it will helpful.

```
<?php

    $categoryid = 12;

    $category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
    $category->load($categoryid);
    $collection = $category->getProductCollection();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    foreach ($collection as $_product) { ?>

    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(200); ?>" width="200" height="200" alt="" /></a> <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $_product->getName(); ?></a>

    <?php } ?>
```

OR you can use this

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id)
 ->getProductCollection()
 ->addAttributeToSelect('*') // add all attributes - optional
 ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1) // enabled
 ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4) //visibility in catalog,search
 ->setOrder('price', 'ASC'); //sets the order by price
```